# 'Command not found' error when trying to scp file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, raspberry-pi, scp

I've installed Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to send a test file from my Macbook to the Pi over my LAN, but I keep getting the error:

```
bash: scp: command not found
```

followed by

```
lost connection
```

I have successfully gotten into the Pi through my Macbook using SSH and the scp command definitely exists on the Pi. Also tried reinstalling OpenSSH-Server on the Pi.

The syntax of my command is:

```
scp afile.rtf pi@xxx.xxx.x.xx:~
```

EDIT: If it's relevant at all, when I run `whereis scp` on the Pi or while SSHing into the Pi on my mac the output is:

```
scp: /usr/bin/scp /usr/share/man/man1/scp.1.gz
```

Comment: Is “pi” an account on the Pi, or on the Mac? Are you running that `scp afile.rtf…` command line on the Mac or on the Pi?

Comment: Try to spot exact location of `scp` on Mac with `which scp` or `whereis scp` commands and call `scp` with full path. Also use full path to the `afile.rtf` file. Suggesting based on this error `bash: scp: command not found` you got.

Comment: Ensure that the `scp` executable on both ends is the correct architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is trying to tell you that your shell cannot find the `scp` command.

It seems you're running this command on the Pi, not on the Mac, because if you were running it on the Mac you should not get such error, as `scp` is normally installed by default, typically in `/usr/bin/scp`, and `/usr/bin` should be on `PATH`. On the other hand, `scp` might not be installed on the Pi, that's why I suspect you're running the command on the wrong machine. So try again, and make sure you are on the Mac's shell, not on the Pi's shell.

You've mentioned the `openssh-server` package. That doesn't include the `scp` tool. Based on your problem description so far, I don't think you need `scp` on the Pi, but if you want to install it, the name of the package that provides it is `openssh-client`.

Comment: I am definitely running the command from the Mac and both machines definitely have it installed. I've read a load of posts that say to make sure you're not currently in an SSH session but that definitely doesn't fit this scenario.

Comment: If your Mac doesn't have the `scp` command, that would be pretty shocking. Run this command to verify: `find / -name scp 2>/dev/null`. It should output the full path of the command. Once you have that, run `/path/to/scp afile.rtf pi@xxx.xxx.x.xx:`, it should work

Comment: Gave that a go janos but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. It *was* to do with the PATH variable. Everything I've read seems to suggest that you can use .bashrc or the environment file to set your PATH variable, and I opted for .bashrc as that seemed to be the traditional way.

I set it in the environment file and it worked.